# Check if web object is front of other web object in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a `webobject` that when I click it I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown
>   error: Element is not clickable at point (128, 605). Other element
>   would receive the click: ...\n 
>   (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.120)\n  (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64)'

The reason is that there is an other object in front of it, namely a message about cookies. So how can I make sure that there is nothing in front of the web object when I click it?

**Example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://cookie-script.com/")
browser.set_window_size(800, 800)

# Click the Start button that is behind the 'Cookies' popup
el=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("id('sp-feature')/div[1]/p[2]/a[1]")[0]
el.click()
```

Comment: Maybe add some javascript/logic, activated only  for your selenium tests, that hides unnecessary pop ups, etc?

Comment: @michaelb well I am testing a website so then it would be bad to do this.

Comment: Well if something is in front of the clickable object, then a real user would have trouble too, so that's not correct either. Perhaps in your tests, first dismiss the cookie message?

Comment: @michaelb That's true. But instead of raising an ugly Selenium exception I would like to tell the user what's wrong..

Comment: Could you elaborate it into a reproduceable example? Would help a lot.

Comment: I have a similar issue once a long time ago, an app opened within Facebook had a particular button that was covered by the old Facebook chat button. I used javascript to delete the Facebook button from the DOM to complete the test. I could make that decision as I was testing the app and not Facebook.

Comment: @alecxe I added an example..

Comment: @Pithikos thanks. Are you looking for a generic solution or the solution that works in this particular case would be ok?

Comment: @alecxe I guess a generic solution that somehow checks if the object can be clicked.. I guess the only reason in Selenium2 that something can't be clicked is because there is something in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have solved it for the moment in a hackish way by simply handling two specific exceptions.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException, StaleElementReferenceException

def click_element(el):
    try:
        el.click()
        return True
    except WebDriverException as exception:
        print("Could not click on element. Maybe something is in front of it?")
    except StaleElementReferenceException as exception:
        print("Reference to element is not valid anymore.")
    return False
```

You can access the exceptions' messages with `exception.msg`

This seems to do it for the moment. I am not sure if I am missing some cases but so far it has worked for me. The good thing is that you get back a `False` if the click didn't succeed, something very helpful since Selenium's `click()` doesn't return anything.